# Codeigniter control subfolder controllers routes

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, routes

I am using two controllers within subfolders but I need to show only the function name in the url rather than controllers.

```
$route['admin/test'] = "admin/sample/test"; 

$route['admin/test1'] = "admin/index/test1";
```

**Admin** is subfolder under controller.

**index** and **sample** are the contollers.

Answer (score 1):

Your routes file should be like this

```
 $route['test'] = 'admin/sample/test';
 $route['test1'] = 'admin/index/test1';
```

Also I would suggest not to have a controller named index. `index()` is a generally a default function in each controller :)

Comment: Thank you very much. it works but for each and every function am creating in two controllers, i have to create a new route in routes.php, is it.

Answer (score 1):

For Codeigniter 3, it is easier, redirect all  methods to the controller, this can be done with a regular expression.

```
$route['admin/([^/]+)'] = 'admin/sample/$1';
```

Documentation: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html#regular-expressions

The $1 represents the first regular expression in the array key, the regular expression must go within the parentheses. If you use more expressions you can use $ 1, $ 2, $ 3 ... etc